# It is possible to create designed xls file in PHP or Laravel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am working as a freelancer and one of my clients asked me to create designed xls file for a Laravel project.

Using Laravel and Maatawebsite for xls files I have generated a xls file using this code:

```
   Excel::create('extract', function ($excel) use ($data) {
        $excel->sheet('mySheet', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
            $sheet->fromArray($data);
        });
    })->download('xls');
```

This function is generating a xls file like this one:

[Generated xls file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHbjg.png)

It is possible to generate something designed like example from bellow using PHP or Laravel?

[How xls file should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TXVL.png)

Comment: Which Excel parsing/writing library is that?

Comment: It's Maatawebsite, extention for laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible, but you'd have to do alot of the styling stuff in your code.

There are a couple of good Excel libraries for PHP available, f.e.

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: Thank you, this is a bit more time consuming but it's working ))